# Recovery Instagram page

Tags: instagram, account-recovery

Just logged in to Instagram with my number(Not connected to email and Facebook either). Now I have forgotten my password. When I forget the password, it sends me a page recovery link, but the problem is that this link does not work, and when I run it in the browser, it brings the main Instagram site and the link does practically nothing. What can I do for this link to bring me the password reset section?